# How to retrieve data from json file

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I am having trouble with accessing my json file from my javascript file. I would like to change the object to a different text in my json file once a submit button is clicked on the webpage. I am aware that I would use ajax to achieve this goal, but I do not know how to access the json file.

This is the db.json file

```
{
{
  "assets": [
    {
      
      "id": "0946",
      "manufacturer": "SONY",
    },
    {
      "id": "0949",
      "manufacturer": "AUDIOTECNIA"
      
    }
],
  "transfers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "status": "in-progress"
    }
               ]
}
```

This is my Javascript file

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        parsedData = JSON.parse(db.json);
        console.log(parsedData[0].id)


    //Changing Status 

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "PATCH",
        url: `http://localhost:3000/transfers/`
        
        
    });
```

I've tried using parseData because I read that is how to retrieve the object, from the json file, but I do not believe I am writing it correctly. What documentation or steps would one recommend for solving this issue?

Comment: parsedData contains the parsed JSON data. Not "objects" as you have written in console.log. if you want to access first element in transfers then it's parsedData.transfers[0].id

Comment: @SuryaK i will change that!

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma after "in-progress",

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(`{ 
   "transfers": [ { 
      "id": 1,      
      "status": "in-progress"
   }]
}`)
```

Then, to access id in parsedData:

```
console.log(parsedData.transfers[0].id)
```

Comment: When I run the code I get a reference error, should there be quotes around "d.json" since it is another file?

Comment: Have you tried removing the extra comma after "in-progress" in the JSON file?

Comment: my JSON file has a ton of other data, so I only cut a snippet of the data, should I post all of the JSON?

Comment: No need. You can check your JSON is correct online, in pages like https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize the variable `parsedData`.

```
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(db.json);
```